# How can I write "onItemClickListener" in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When I will click on any Item of RecyclerView. It will show me the details of this item. How can I do that? I have used Retrofit library. I have created a adapter for this RecyclerView. I have mentioned it bellow.

Activity:

```
List<TargetFile> targetfiles=response.body().getTargetfileslist();

Log.d(TAG,"Number of targetfileslist: "+targetfiles.size());
recyclerView.setAdapter(new TargetFileAdapter(targetfiles,R.layout.list_item_targetfile,getApplicationContext()));  //RecyclerView
```

Adapter:

```
public class TargetFileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TargetFileAdapter.TargetFileViewHolder> {

    private List<TargetFile> targetfiles;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public TargetFileAdapter(List<TargetFile> targetfiles, int rowLayout, Context context) {
        this.targetfiles = targetfiles;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }



    public static class TargetFileViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        LinearLayout targetFilesLayout;
        TextView fileno,partyname,mobile,address;

        public TargetFileViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            targetFilesLayout=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.targetfile_layout);
            fileno=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.fileno);
            partyname=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.partyname);
            address=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.adrs);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TargetFileAdapter.TargetFileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout,parent,false);
        return new TargetFileViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TargetFileViewHolder holder,final int position){
        holder.fileno.setText(targetfiles.get(position).getFileno());
        holder.partyname.setText(targetfiles.get(position).getPartyname());
        holder.address.setText(targetfiles.get(position).getAddress());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return targetfiles.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: make `TargetFileViewHolder` implements `OnClickListener` and call `setOnClickListener` in `TargetFileViewHolder` constructor

Comment: You can create an `OnItemClickListener` on a `RecyclerView` but if you can get by with a `ListView`, it already has one built in.

Answer (score 2):

1.Create an interface

```
public interface CustomItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View v, int position);
}
```

2.Adapter

```
CustomItemClickListener customItemClickListener;
public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Data> dataset, CustomItemClickListener customItemClickListener) {
    inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data= dataset;
    this.customItemClickListener = customItemClickListener;
}

public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.password_list_items, parent, false);
    final MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            customItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, myViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
    return myViewHolder;
}
```

3.Activity

```
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), dataset, new CustomItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }));
```

It worked for me, I hope it will help you

Comment: I don't get the position. Position is same for all.

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new TargetFileAdapter(targetfiles, R.layout.list_item_targetfile, getApplicationContext(), new TargetFileAdapter.CustomItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }));

Comment: What position does it give?

Answer (score 1):

iimport android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;

```
public class TargetFileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TargetFileAdapter.TargetFileViewHolder> {

    private List<TargetFile> targetfiles;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;
    private OnTargetFileListener listener;

    public TargetFileAdapter(List<TargetFile> targetfiles, int rowLayout, Context context, OnTargetFileListener listener) {
        this.targetfiles = targetfiles;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public TargetFileAdapter.TargetFileViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new TargetFileViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TargetFileViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.fileno.setText(targetfiles.get(position).getFileno());
        holder.partyname.setText(targetfiles.get(position).getPartyname());
        holder.address.setText(targetfiles.get(position).getAddress());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return targetfiles.size();
    }

    public static class TargetFileViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        LinearLayout targetFilesLayout;
        TextView fileno, partyname, mobile, address;

        public TargetFileViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            targetFilesLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.targetfile_layout);
            fileno = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fileno);
            partyname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.partyname);
            address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.adrs);

            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (listener == null){
                return;
            }

            TargetFile file = targetfiles.get(getAdapterPosition());
            listener.onFileTargetClicked(file);
        }
    }

    public interface OnTargetFileListener {
        void onTargetFileClicked(TargetFile file);
    }
}
```

This code should work for you. You need to implement OnTargetFileListener in your activity or where you use adapter.

Good luck!

Emre.